# ng-show together with ng-if and css animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have css animations working based on the `ng-show` directive in Angular.
I'm trying to add `ng-if` directives to help me reduce the number of DOM elements in my page by removing hidden parts of it.

```
<div class="some classes" ng-show="isActive()" ng-if="isActive()">
  <div class="other elements">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the `ng-if` removes the element before it gets the chance to disappear "nicely".

The animation is a rollingUp/Down sort of animation and the outer div has a variable height dependent on the content of the inner div. I tried moving the `ng-if` down, but the problem stays the same as the height suddenly becomes 0 once the `ng-if` is true.

What would be the (best) strategy to achieve this? My main goal is to reduce the number of elements without sacrificing the animations.

*(I'm using angular 1.2.0)*

Comment: Why are you using the ngShow directive together with the ngIf directive? Yyou should use one of them, and not both on the same element. You can animate the ngIf [yearofmoo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html#animating-nginclude-ngview-and-ngif) got some great examples.

Comment: The ng-show I use for the animations and the ng-if to try to remove the elements afterwards

Comment: ngIf can be animated too take a look at link I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: I was so sure ngIf could not be animated I didn't even check... Thanks for your answer!

Comment: `ng-if` has bigger **priority** than `ng-show` that's why it is executed first.

Comment: Why are you removing already compiled DOM? You already paid the time price in loading it. ng-if is more for "don't load AT ALL until another condition" which would make sense if you were trying to speed up your initial load times, but in your case you already loaded them. Now you are going to remove them, and then perhaps reload them over and over again.